# Word 2007 files on emacs?

Tags: microsoft-word, emacs, microsoft-word-2007

Is there a word-2007 mode for emacs?

Answer (score 3):

[Some Livejournaler](http://johnsu01.livejournal.com/204993.html) is making use of [a macro](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki?no-word.el) and [antiword](http://directory.fsf.org/project/antiword/) combination.

> #### Antiword
>
> Antiword is a free MS-Word reader for GNU/Linux, RISC OS, and DOS. It converts the documents from Word 2, 6, 7, 97, 2000, 2002, and 2003 to text, Postscript, and XML/DocBook. Antiword tries to keep the layout of the document intact.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not word '07. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit docx files, you can treat them as raw XML (docx files are a ZIPped bundle of XML files), which can sometimes be useful, but isn't acceptable for seriously engaing with the content.  This could, I think, in principle, be launched from `archive-mode`.

Or you can convert them to Latex using [docx2tex](http://www.codeplex.com/docx2tex/), which works pretty well, but loses some formatting.  `docx2tex` isn't packaged up by anyone, and if you are on Linux, you'll need to install some pretty up-to-date Mono libraries.  Unfortunately, converting back again doesn't work so well: there are a few fairly limited Latex to RTF converters around.

That's not really the same thing as an existing `word-2007-mode`, but the steps could all be automated in Emacs.

Comment: Hmmmmm. I would prefer to seriously engage with the content though. :(

Comment: @Paul: Wait, it should come.  Bith AbiWord & OO support docx in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be some scripts for the older .doc format called no-word as well as antiword.  You might want to look into these or their updates/derivates.

Comment: Yeah, didn't look like '07 was supported.